# Downside to doing a SetAuthCookie every request

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

For the past few months, we've had users complaining that their authentication was sometimes expiring early - after only 20 minutes of inactivity, despite the fact that we have authentication timeouts set to 30.  I discovered today that SlidingExpiration only resets when there's less than half of the auth time left, leaving open the possibility of doing something, waiting ten minutes, doing something else, waiting 21 minutes, and getting an 'early' timeout.

Are there any potential downsides to doing something like this in my Master Page's Page_Load?

```
if(CurrentUser != null) {
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(CurrentUser.UserName, false);
}
```

...and thus resetting the sliding expiration with every request?

**Edit:**

This code is what I wound up using; it only resets the token once per minute.

```
var cookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);

if (ticket.IssueDate.AddMinutes(1) < DateTime.Now && ticket.IssueDate.AddMinutes(30) > DateTime.Now) {
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(currentUser.UserName, false);
}
```

Comment: Two notes about the code: 1) I'm pretty sure they can't get there with an expired ticket, but I made sure not to reset it if they're over 30 minutes old.  2) currentUser is a variable from our application; if you try to compile this directly it won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest downside is that it will disable caching, e.g. <%@ OutputCache %> directives will no longer function correctly.  So you might start seeing a performance hit due to cache misses.

If you're able to, the easiest thing to do would be to bump the expiration timeout.

Comment: We couldn't bump the timeout, but I did set it to only renew if it's been at least a minute.  Still not great performance, but it does keep the timeout reliably between 29 and 30 minutes.